# How to find which Parent Object created a child Object

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, tapestry

I have a manager which is called by several different classes. The manager is instantiate through a Inject. So when I'm debugging I need to know who instantiate this manager? is there any way to do this?

Comment: If it's injected, then the container (i.e. Spring, CDI or Guice, depending on which DI framework you're using) is the one instantiating it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not unless the caller passes itself to the method which creates the manager and is then passed to the constructor of the manager which then stores it in a private variable. When you don't track this information explicitely, it will be lost.

Alternatively, you could also set a debugging breakpoint in the constructor of the manager and when the breakpoint is hit examine the call stack to find out from where it is called.

Answer (score 0):

One way to find out which object instantiates your manager is to create a stack trace in the constructor of the manager. Use Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace() to get an array of StackTraceElements.

When debugging, simply inspect this array of StackTraceElements to see which object created the manager.